# count index in stream

Tags: java, indexing, java-8, java-stream

I have a stream. I want to count the index in stream ( I need a number of row with incorrect signature "сумм" ). 
I want to verify number of index in my `LinkedList`.
  my code :

```
    Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, List<RosterRow>>>>>> rost = roster.getRows().stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(RosterRow::getBeneficiarySurname,
                    Collectors.groupingBy(RosterRow::getBeneficiaryName,
                            Collectors.groupingBy(RosterRow::getBeneficiaryPatronymic,
                                    Collectors.groupingBy(RosterRow::getBeneficiaryIdentificationDocumentSerial,
                                            Collectors.groupingBy(RosterRow::getBeneficiaryIdentificationDocumentNumber)
                                    )))));
    rost.entrySet().stream()
            .map(entry -> rost.get(entry.getKey()))
            .map(each -> each.entrySet())
            .flatMap(Collection::stream)
            .map(entry -> entry.getValue())
            .map(each -> each.entrySet())
            .flatMap(Collection::stream)
            .map(entry -> entry.getValue())
            .map(each -> each.entrySet())
            .flatMap(Collection::stream)
            .map(entry -> entry.getValue())
            .map(each -> each.entrySet())
            .flatMap(Collection::stream)
            .map(entry -> entry.getValue())

            .forEach(group -> {    
                List<String> indexes = group.stream()
                        .filter(row -> row.getComment().contains("сумма"))
                        .map(RosterRow::getComment)
                        .map(s -> s.substring(s.length() - 1))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
                int numberofrows = group.size();                
                List <String> places = new ArrayList<>();
                for (int i = 1; i < numberofrows + 1; i++) {
                    places.add(Integer.toString(i));
                };
                if (!indexes.containsAll(places)) {
                    throw new InvalidAccrualException(String.format("%s: %s", bundle.getString("Invalid_field_value"), "NOTE"));
                }
            });
    return Collections.EMPTY_LIST;
}
```

Comment: So what's wrong here? Your code does not compile? Throws exception? Produces incorrect result? Which result is desired then?

Comment: I need to count the index of row with incorrect  row.getComment().contains("сумма")) in original collection not in group.

Comment: @Jack, ok, updated answer

Comment: Thanks works for me .

Answer (score 2):

To get the number of row you can write:

```
List<RosterRow> rows = roster.getRows();
OptionalInt index = IntStream.range(0, rows.size())
         .filter(idx -> rows.get(idx).getComment().contains("сумма"))
         .findFirst();
```